# Calculations using checkboxes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to front end development and angular . I'm trying to perform calculations on the UI. Im building a segment on my page something similar to this 
a+b+c+d/a+b+c+d =r 
here a,b,c,d are check boxes and the values are applied when they are checked . For instance , a and b are checked in the numerator whose values are 1,2 and d is checked in the denominator with value 3 the final equation will be 1+2/3=1

Comment: You can refer docs here and write your code - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: Can you show some code? Better if you can create a Stackblitz example.

Comment: used below function to solve this issue     function checkTotal() {
  document.listForm.total.value = '';
  var sum1 = 0;
  var sum2 = 0;
  for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice1.length;i++) {
    if (document.listForm.choice1[i].checked) {
     sum1 = sum1 + parseInt(document.listForm.choice1[i].value);
    }
  }
  for (i=0;i<document.listForm.choice2.length;i++) {
    if (document.listForm.choice2[i].checked) {
     sum2 = sum2 + parseInt(document.listForm.choice2[i].value);
    }
  }
  document.listForm.total.value = sum1/sum2;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for the FormGroup apporach.
declare a form with FormControl names like - a,b,d,e.
And do calculations on the valueChange event of the each FormControl.

Please let me know if you need any further help.